# How to access to items inside the menu item (JMenu) java

Tags: java, netbeans-platform, jmenu

I want to switch language in my netbeans platform application and I need to access to the text in all JMenu items

I use this code :

```
int iCount = JM.getItemCount();
                        for (int i = 0; i < iCount; i++) {
                                JMenuItem itemObject = JM.getItem(i);
                                if (itemObject != null ) {
                                     itemObject.setText("newtext") ;                                   

                            }

                        }
```

it Changes the item text ,but the display text does not change.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch/update with get/setText() on JMenuItem

Comment: the item text has changed but the display text not.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
    menu.add(new JMenuItem("Open ..."));
    menu.add(new AbstractAction("Exit") {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });

    for (int i=0; i<menu.getItemCount(); ++i) {
      System.err.println("Text: " + menu.getItem(i).getText());
    }
  }
}
```